# Форматирование времени из timestamp с минутами и секундами в выходной строке в зависимости от локали

Tags: java, android, время

Задача заключается в том, чтобы в зависимости от локали (код страны задан в формате Alpha-2 ISO 3166-1 (например RU или US)) форматировать timestamp заданный в миллисекундах в строку, содержащую сокращение от минут или секунд. Например 00 мин. 25 сек.
Например, при значение timestamp = 6000 конвертировать в "00 мин. 6 с." если стоит русская локаль, и в "00 m. 6 s." если английская.
Знаю точно, что можно вставлять названия месяцев, или дней недели, но можно ли сделать для минут и секунд?

Comment: то есть вы получаете к примеру 6000 и это вам нужно конвертировать?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko да, именно! причём сокращённая запись мин. и с. зависит от того, какая локаль у нас установлена.

Answer (score 0):

Вот есть способ рабочий:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
TimeZone tz = cal.getTimeZone();

/* debug: is it local time? */
Log.d("Time zone: ", tz.getDisplayName());

/* date formatter in local timezone */
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
sdf.setTimeZone(tz);

/* print your timestamp and double check it's the date you expect */
long timestamp = cursor.getLong(columnIndex);
String localTime = sdf.format(new Date(timestamp * 1000));
Log.d("Time: ", localTime);
```

либо второй вариант:

```
long timestamp = cursor.getLong(columnIndex);
Log.d("Server time: ", timestamp);

/* log the device timezone */
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
TimeZone tz = cal.getTimeZone();
Log.d("Time zone: ", tz.getDisplayName());

/* log the system time */
Log.d("System time: ", System.currentTimeMillis());

CharSequence relTime = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
    timestamp * 1000,
    System.currentTimeMillis(),
    DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS);

((TextView) view).setText(relTime);
```

[ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853389/how-to-convert-utc-timestamp-to-device-local-time-in-android) на первоисточник.